# How can I center an area of an image map?

Tags: javascript, image, dictionary, area, imagemap

I'm working on a responsive image map with about 50 areas in it.
I did a menu and I want when I clicked some item of the menu the image map make a zoom and center the selected area in the middle of the screen
How can I do that? I'm working with rwdImageMaps and JQuery Pan Zoom

I tried with this function but just found when the screen is big and the smaller devices not work beacuse are other points

`function go(x,y){
    var $section = $('section').first();
    var $elem=$section.find('.panzoom').panzoom();
    $elem.panzoom("reset");
    $elem.panzoom("zoom",3);
    $elem.panzoom("pan",x,y);
}`

Comment: image map…? please please please tell me what you are working on.  Is this an email? I haven't seen the need for an image map since 2001.

Comment: @vol7ron i'm doing a local map from my town, it's an interactive map.

Comment: Not saying you're going about it the wrong way, but you may want to post an example.  Usually image maps can be replaced with either absolute positioning of internal HTML elements, or using SVG.